# How can I fix an unconfirmed low-fee transaction sent from Multibit HD?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit-hd

I have tried researching this issue for hours. I do not think the majority of usual solutions are possible with Multibit HD. The only solution I believe I do not fully understand (and therefore it may be possible) is

1) Repair/Restart the wallet multiple times, hoping to get lucky and have it connect to a node that will handle a low fee transaction.

2) Something to do with Bitcoin Core. This looks promising, but I don't believe there even are "wallet.dat" files with Multibit HD, so I'm not sure how to execute these directions:

[Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/4ggg0m/how_do_i_run_command_line_on_the_bitcoin_core/

Information on my situation:

I accidentally sent some transactions with an extremely low fee. Judging by the mempool, it could take 48~ hours for these transactions to process. I would like to "cancel" these transactions, and resend them for a higher fee. With a wallet balance of 0 and no way to implement any of the common methods to orphan blocks... is there any way I can recall my coins?

If not, how long does it take before the transactions are dropped? I read that if every node in the network looks at my transaction and denies it, then it will be recalled even with Multibit HD, is that true?

TX ID:  7f078efec60078aa4575cc6fb3f4064886fb3a88b0a5078069d86bb29ebe55bc

"before txs" is certainly not following a downward trend...oftentimes when I check, the number has increased up into the 15,000 but never lower than 8,000.

What are my options?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @UTF-8: That's not the right duplicate target, as btchelp already states in his question that he saw it, but it didn't solve his problem.

Comment: also related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54182/multibit-hd-0-5-1-with-unconfirmed-transactions-for-months-now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multibit HD 0.5.1 with Unconfirmed transactions for months now](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54182/multibit-hd-0-5-1-with-unconfirmed-transactions-for-months-now)